# Add component dynamically with cdk/ComponentPortal

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to add a component dynamically using cdk's ComponentPortal

```
@Component {
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div #container></div>',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
}
export class AppComponent  {
    @ViewChild('container',  {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false}) container;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
        const dialogContent = new ComponentPortal(BarfooComponent, this.container);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dn43dj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

As you can see from the demo this code doesn't throw any errors, but also renders nothing :(

So, I'm not sure if anything like this is even possible with `ComponentPortal` and if so I probably miss one or more steps here. Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach the created component portal. You can do it through the directives like cdkPortalOutlet or manually. [CDK Docs Portals](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) - it docs for Portals, which gives the examples on how to do it.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdvizy) is fixed example on stackblitz. Don't forget to include PortalModule from `@angular/cdk/portal`. This module provides `cdkOverlayPortal` directive.

Looks like you want to create dialog. Angular CDK provides abstractions for such case: Portals and Overlays.

So the plan is: 
- create a portal
- create an overlay
- attach the portal to the overlay

So [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zb73op) is the demo using overlays & portals.

If I remember correctly, you also have to add prebuilt styles from the cdk. You have to add them into `architect.build.options.styles` array of your `angular.json` file. You have to add something like `node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css` there. If you use custom bundle you have to handle it manually.

[CDK Docs Overlays](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) - more information about overlays is in the docs.

Comment: Wait! I also added info about overlays. I think if you create dialog it will fit your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have it working! One last question, In my case I would like to bind stuff the the components `@input` and listen to its `@Output`s. Is there any way using the `cdkPortalOutlet` to get access to the instance of the component?

Comment: It looks like it is not so hard :) [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38gvlg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Wait, no setTimeout. `this.userSettingsPortal.component` is enough. You have it immidiately.

Comment: Without the `setTimeout` I get the following error: `ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined`

Comment: Don't use ref to the cdkOutletPortal. You have component instance as the result of new Component Portal

Comment: I don't see how you can extract the instance from the `userSettingsPortal` from `this.userSettingsPortal = new ComponentPortal(BarfooComponent);` or from `this.container` ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38gvlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

Comment: My bad, you are right for this case. Case with overlay attach was in my mind. Here is working demo with overlay attach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyx59e. CdkPortalOutlet has attached output. You can use it. Here is the demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38gvlg Still async, but you don't have magic setTimeout.

Comment: I managed to remove the`setTimeout` :) [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38gvlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) What I did was move the assignment code to `ngOnInit` and than you have the instance in `ngAfterViewInit`!!